# Prove property of floor function (one with square roots)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I want to prove that:
$$\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor=\lfloor\sqrt{\lfloor x\rfloor}\rfloor$$

It's true that (by definition of floor operation):
$$\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor\leq\sqrt{x}<\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor+1$$
$$\lfloor\sqrt{\lfloor x\rfloor}\rfloor\leq\sqrt{\lfloor x\rfloor}<\lfloor\sqrt{\lfloor x\rfloor}\rfloor+1$$

But I don't know what comes next. Tried multiple conversions of those inequalities, but I did not see anything. Can you help?

Comment: Consider $(\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor)^2$ and $(\lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor +1)^2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, thank you, I almost got this:
$$\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor\leq\sqrt{x}<\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor+1$$
  means that $$\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor^{2}\leq x<(\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor+1)^{2}$$
Knowing that $$\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor^{2}\leq\lfloor x\rfloor\leq x<(\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor+1)^{2}$$
we come to $$\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor\leq\sqrt{\lfloor x\rfloor}\leq\sqrt{x}<(\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor+1)$$
Where $\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor$ and $(\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor+1)$ are next numbers.

But i have one problem here. How to prove that 
$\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor^{2}\leq\lfloor x\rfloor\leq x$?

Comment: That's good. We know $\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor^2 \leqslant \lfloor x\rfloor$ because we know that $\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor^2$ is an integer. And we know it's $\leqslant x$, so it must be $\leqslant \lfloor x\rfloor$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thank you very much for your answer, you've helped me a lot ;)

Comment: One can prove a more general statement:
Let $f$ be any continuous and strictly increasing function with the property that if $f(x)$ is an integer, then so is $x$. Then
 \begin{align*}
 \bigg\lfloor f(\lfloor x \rfloor)\bigg\rfloor  = \bigg\lfloor f(x) \bigg\rfloor \quad \text{and} \quad \bigg\lceil f(\lceil x \rceil)\bigg\rceil  = \bigg\lceil f(x) \bigg\rceil.
 \end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Using the implicit condition $x\ge 0$, we have for $n\in\mathbb N_0$
$$\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor <n\iff \sqrt x<n\iff x<n^2$$
and 
$$\left\lfloor \sqrt{\lfloor x\rfloor}\right\rfloor <n\iff \sqrt{\lfloor x\rfloor}<n\iff\lfloor x\rfloor <n^2\iff x<n^2.$$
Since both $\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor$ and $\left\lfloor \sqrt{\lfloor x\rfloor}\right\rfloor$ are in $\mathbb N_0$, this suffices to show equality.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see why it suffices to show equality. Why proving that both of there are equivalent to
$$x<n^2$$
is enough?

Comment: @KamilSołtysik He uses $\;k = l \;\equiv\; \langle \forall n :: k < n \equiv l < n \rangle\;$, for $\;k,l,n \in {\mathbb N}_0\;$.

Answer (score 1):

Using
$$
\tag{0} n = m \;\equiv\; \langle \forall k :: k \le n \equiv k \le m \rangle
$$
for integer $\;n,m,k\;$, this is proved by the following calculation: for all $\;k\;$, we have
\begin{align}
& k \le \left\lfloor \sqrt{\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor} \right\rfloor \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"by $(1)$ below, since $\;k\;$ is integer"} \\
& k \le \sqrt{\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor} \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"square both sides, using RHS $\;\ge 0\;$"} \\
& k < 0 \;\lor\; k^2 \le \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"by $(1)$ below, since $\;k^2\;$ is integer"} \\
& k < 0 \;\lor\; k^2 \le x \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"in second part: square root of both sides, using RHS $\;\ge 0\;$"} \\
& k \le \sqrt{x} \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"by (1) below, since $\;k\;$ is integer"} \\
& k \le \left\lfloor \sqrt{x} \right\rfloor \\
\end{align}

Here I used
$$
\tag{1} k \le \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor \;\equiv\; k \le x
$$
where $\;k\;$ is integer and $\;x\;$ is real.

---

After I finished typing the above, I noticed that this is just like [Hagen von Eitzen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/39174/hagen-von-eitzen)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/524519/11994), except that he uses the equivalent
$$
\tag{0'} n = m \;\equiv\; \langle \forall k :: n < k \equiv m < k \rangle
$$
and
$$
\tag{1'} \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor < k \;\equiv\; x < k
$$
and he lets $\;n,m,k\;$ range over the natural numbers.  And my proof is in the calculational format which I've learned like a lot (for background information, see the second part of [EWD1300](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html)).

Answer (score 0):

In fact,we have
$$[\sqrt{[\sqrt{x}]}]=[\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}]$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=i+f$ where $i\in \Bbb{Z},f\in[0,1)$ .

$\therefore\sqrt x=\sqrt{i+f}$

Now $\exists g\in[0,1)$ such that $0<g<f$ and $f=2\sqrt ig+g^2$

Also $\exists h\in[0,1)$ such that $h>f$ and $f=-2\sqrt ih+h^2$

So $$\sqrt x=\sqrt i+g=\sqrt i-h$$

However $[\sqrt i]\leq [\sqrt i+g]\le [\sqrt i]+1$ and $[\sqrt i]-1\leq [\sqrt i-h]\le [\sqrt i]$

$$\therefore [\sqrt i+g]=[\sqrt i-h]=[\sqrt i]\\\implies [\sqrt x]=\left[\sqrt[2][x]\right]$$